# Using array_count_values in foreach loop

Tags: php

I would like the sample output as below.

1: 2 occurrences

2: 3 occurrences

3: 2 occurrences

4: 1 occurrence

5: 1 occurrence

7: 1 occurrence

the number of occurrences is based on the user input in a form format. Below is the Html code that I use for the user to type in the number.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
h1{
text-align:center;
}
form{
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
border-style: solid;
width:700px;
height:250px;
}
</style>
<body>

<form action="page2" method="get">
<h1>Algorithm Calculator</h1>
<label for="fname">Enter Number with Comma <br> eg: 
1,2,3,4,4,5,5,7</label><br><br>
<input type="text" id="number" name="number"><br> 
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Second-page code

```
<?php
$number=$_GET['number'];
$result = array();
$result = explode(',',$number);
foreach ($result as $value){
echo "$value = ".array_count_values($result) 
[$value]." occurrences <br>";
}
?>
```

I only want my code to loop once but it loop more than once if the user input the same number twice. Below is my output.

1 = 1 occurrences

2 = 1 occurrences

3 = 1 occurrences

4 = 2 occurrences

4 = 2 occurrences (i do not want this to loop twice)

Comment: You can do this without the loop, this seems like the correct answer you are after ```$occurences = array_count_values($result);```

Comment: Unrelated fyi: the `for` attribute in a `<label>` should point to an `id`, yours is `number`, not `fname`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to handle the user input then before going inside your loop.

```
$result = explode(',',$number);
foreach (array_unique($result) as $value){
   echo "$value = ".array_count_values($result) 
   [$value]." occurrences <br>";
}
```

You will keep only the unique values in your array so you will loop only once per value.

Answer (score 1):

`array_count_values` function provides the unique elements in an array as the keys and also provides the number of occurrences as the values in the array. So the solution can be as mentioned below:

```
<?php
    $number=$_GET['number'];
    $result = array();
    $result = explode(',',$number);
    foreach (array_count_values($result) as $key => $value) {
        echo "{$key} = {$value} occurrences <br />";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the result of the a `array_count_values()` and its easy.

```
$number='9,9,4,4,22,22,22';
$result = explode(',',$number);
print_r(array_count_values($result));

foreach(array_count_values($result) as $n=>$occ) {
    echo "$n = $occ occurrences <br />" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

RESULT

The `array_count_value()` produces an array with the key being the numbers being counted and the value as the occurances of the numbers

```
Array
(
    [9] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [22] => 3
)
```

So the output is

```
9 = 2 occurrences <br />
4 = 2 occurrences <br />
22 = 3 occurrences <br />
```